# Splitting strings and placing it into respective columns in datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a List(Of String), I want to display it on my Datagridview wherein this Datagridview's column headers have been set. I want to split the one-line string from the list to the columns in the Datagridview. Here is the example of what I want to be displayed:

This is the strings on the list:

```
String 1|String 2|String 3
String a|String b|String c
```

And here is what I want it to look like on the Datagridview:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
String 1  String 2  String 3
String a  String b  String c
```

This is what I have so far:

```
For Each mail In emailList

    Dim rowStringCollection As String() = mail.Split(New String() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    For Each rowString As String In rowStringCollection
        Dim rowData As String() = rowString.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        'Insert the strings into the table

    Next

    dgvMails.DataSource = table
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
For Each mail In emailList
    Dim rowStringCollection As String() = mail.Split(New String() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    DataGridView.Rows.Add(New String() {rowStringCollection(0), rowStringCollection(1), rowStringCollection(2), rowStringCollection(3), rowStringCollection(4)})
Next
```

Comment: Shorter solution: `DataGridView.Rows.Add(mail.Split("|"c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - because `Split` method return same type which expected in the `Rows.Add` method